# How to extract indexes from strings?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, ash

My file contains data as indicated below:

```
{ "any1", "aaa.bbb.ccc.1.ddd", "var1" }
{ "any2", "aaa.bbb.ccc.1.eee", "toto" }
{ "an42", "aaa.bbb.ccc.1.fff", "titi" }
{ "an47", "aaa.bbb.ccc.2.eee", "var3" }
{ "any7", "aaa.bbb.ccc.2.ddd", "var12" }
{ "a789", "aaa.bbb.ccc.2.fff", "var14" }
{ "any1", "xxx.yyy.zzz.1.ddd", "var1" }
{ "any2", "xxx.yyy.zzz.1.eee", "toto" }
{ "an42", "xxx.yyy.zzz.1.fff", "titi" }
```

I want to extract the all indexes of the prefix `"aaa.bbb.ccc"`

So the command should return

```
linux# command
1
2
```

How I can make that with `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, `sort`?

Comment: do you also need to check the leading double quote or just `aaa.bbb.ccc.`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can for example say:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=aaa\.bbb\.ccc\.)\d*' file | sort -u
1
2
```

#### Step by step

Get the digit after `aaa\.bbb\.ccc\.` (note we escape the dots to match the dot itself, not any character):

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=aaa\.bbb\.ccc\.)\d*' file
1
1
1
2
2
2
```

`sort` them and find the unique values:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=aaa\.bbb\.ccc\.)\d*' file | sort -u
1
2
```

---

### Alternative with `sed`

If you don't have the `-P` option in your `grep`, you can use `sed`:

```
$ sed -nr 's/^.*aaa\.bbb\.ccc\.([0-9]+).*$/\1/p' file
1
1
1
2
2
2
$ sed -nr 's/^.*aaa\.bbb\.ccc\.([0-9]+).*$/\1/p' file | sort -u
1
2
```

Comment: `(?<=aaa\.bbb\.ccc\.)` ?

Comment: grep: The -P option is not supported: libpcre.so.3 is not available

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works with sed and I used `sort -u` instead of  `sort | uniq`

Comment: @MOHAMED that is a good addition. I just edited the answer to use `sort -u`, thanks!

Comment: Now if the "aaa.bbb.ccc" is defined in variable. `var="aaa.bbb.ccc"`, what should be the `sed` command  with the `var`

Comment: if we use `sed -nr "s/^.*$var([0-9]+).*$/\1/p"`, does the `'.'` (of the `var`) are treated as real `'.'`? or they are treated as any char regexp?

Comment: @MOHAMED why don't you do a test with some data? I did and yes, you have to escape them: `var="aaa\.bbb\.ccc\."`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/.*aaa\.bbb\.ccc\.\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*/ {s//\1/;H;}
   $!d
   s/.*//;H;x
:a
   s/\(\n[^[:cntrl:]]*\)\(.*\)\1\n/\1\2\
/
   ta
   s/.\(.*\)./\1/p' YourFile
```

for fun and in 1 (posix) sed, not sorted. (GNU sed allow a online version)

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` alternative:

```
$ awk -F\. '/aaa.bbb.ccc.[0-9]+/{b=$(NF-1);if (!(b in a)){ print b}a[b]++}' infile
```

Steps:

1. Set the `FS` separator to `dot`
2. Look for the wanted pattern
3. Store index value in `b` variable
4. Use an associative array `a`  to mark the printed index keys.
5. If `b` not in `a` print the index ( key of a )